# Validate if a property in my model is higher than another property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I have this model which contains the two following properties:

```
public int m_ID
public int m_NbrInStock
public int m_QtyToShow
```

Here is I actually render my view:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selectAll").click(function ()
        {
            var chkValue = $(this).is(":checked");
            $(".divChckBox").prop("checked", chkValue);
        });
    });
</script>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SendItems", "Inventory"))
    {
        <p>
            Select / UnSelet All Items @Html.CheckBox("selectAll", true) 
        </p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Obj Name</th>
                <th>Number In Stock</th>
                (...)
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].m_Card.m_CardName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].m_NbInStock)</td>
                    (...)
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="itemSending" class="divChckBox" checked="true" value="@Model[i].m_ID"/>
                    </td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].m_QtyToShow</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
        <div class="float-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
        </div>
    }
</p>
```

I have many problems here:

1. First of all, I need to keep the QtyToShow as it will later be used for data managing, but the data does not survive the model because of the HTTPPost;
2. I also need to validate that QtyToShow is never higher than m_NbrInStock or show an error message if that's the case.

This is not a simple task and since I don't have much experience in MVC development I don't know how I could do this. Can you help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

- Validate the data manually in the controller
- Write a custom validator

The first one is the easiest, the second is a better practice.

To get you off the ground and get your app working, you can implement the first way, and then come back and refactor when you're more comfortable with mvc.

So add a property to your viewModel

```
public string QuantityValidationMsg {get; set}
```

Then in your view display the message

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].m_QtyToShow
 <span>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].m_QuantityValidationMsg)</span></td>
```

Then in your post action (which needs to accept a `List<yourViewModel>`, *not* a `List<int>`, btw)

```
viewModel.QuantityValidationMsg = null;
if (viewModel.QtyToShow > viewModel.NbrInStock)
{
  viewModel.QuantityValidationMsg = "Error Message!";
}
```

For the second approach, you would create a new class that implements `ValidationAttribute`
and define something along the lines of:

```
public class ValidateQuantity : ValidateAttribute
{
  private const string MESSAGE = "Error Message";
  public ValidateQuantity (int qtyInput, int qtyConfirm)
      : base( MESSAGE )
  {
     Input = qtyInput;
     Confirm = qtyConfirm;
  }

  public int Input {get; private set;}
  public int Confirm {get; private set;}

  public override bool IsValid (object value)
  {
    var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);
    var input = properties.Find(Input, false).GetValue(value); 
    var confirm = properties.Find(Confirm, false).GetValue(value); 
    if( input > confirm)
    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then decorate the model property with the new attribute

```
public int m_ID
public int m_NbrInStock

[ValidateQuantity]
public int m_QtyToShow
```

And add the validation message in the view

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.m_QtyToShow)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will evaluate what I do with this case and the information you have given me. Thanks!

Comment: As I worked on your solution, I finally understood that since I did not originally sent the list<mymodel> back to the httppost method, any modification made would not be saved. Changing this has helped me a lot! Thank you once again. :)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is terribly easy to express in Mkay, a custom attribute I wrote for ad hoc rules like this. It's available as a nuget package. After installing, all you need to do is annotate your model property like this:

```
[Mkay(">= m_NbrInStock")]
public int m_QtyToShow
```

If you're interested, you can read more about how Mkay works at my blog: https://einarwh.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/mkay-one-validation-attribute-to-rule-them-al/

Comment: Of course I am interested, I will go read about it right away :)